# jsonwebtoken Typescript Compiling issue?

Tags: typescript, json-web-token

I'm trying to compile a typescript file and it keeps throwing this error from the compiler:
`error TS2339: Property 'payload' does not exist on type 'string | object'.
  Property 'payload' does not exist on type 'string'.`

Code in question:

```
decode(token: string): any {
  const decodedJWT = jwt.decode(token, { complete: true });

  const issuer = decodedJWT.payload.iss;
                           ^^^^^^^^^
  return {};
}
```

I'm using the `@types/jsonwebtoken` library to define the types.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What type does `jwt.decode` return?

Answer (score 6):

This error is caused by TypeScript type checking, the return type of `jwt.decode()` is `null | object | string`, if you're sure `jwt.decode()` always returns an object, you can cast `decodedJWT` to `any` type to avoid this error:

```
decode(token: string): any {
  const decodedJWT = jwt.decode(token, { complete: true });

  const issuer = (decodedJWT as any).payload.iss;
  return {};
}
```

In the above example, it might cause exception at runtime, because `jwt.decode()` might return `null` or a string, but only an [`object`](https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2017/02/24/typescript-2-2-the-object-type) contains property `payload`, so you'd better handle the return value in a safer way:

```
decode(token: string): any {
  const decodedJWT = jwt.decode(token, { complete: true });

  if (decodedJWT === null) {
       // deal with null
  } else if (typeof decodedJWT === 'string') {
       // deal with string
  } else {
       const issuer = (decodedJWT as any).payload.iss; // cast to `any` type
  }

  return {};
}
```